# pipenv `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.basecommand`

Tags: pipenv, virtual-environment

I'm trying to create a virtual environment using **pipenv**. When I give the command **pipenv install**, I get the following error

I am using **pipenv==2018.6.25**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib_compat.py", line 33, in do_import
>           _tmp = importlib.import_module(internal)
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.basecommand'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>           "**main**", mod_spec)
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>           exec(code, run_globals)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pipenv.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv__init__.py", line 23, in 
>           from .cli import cli
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli.py", line 26, in 
>           from .utils import is_valid_url
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 59, in 
>           from .vendor.requirementslib import Requirement
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib__init__.py", line 6, in 
>           from .models import Requirement, Lockfile, Pipfile
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models__init__.py", line 8, in 
>           from .requirements import Requirement
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 15, in 
>           from .markers import PipenvMarkers
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\markers.py", line 6, in 
>           from .utils import validate_markers, filter_none
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\utils.py", line 9, in 
>           from .._compat import Link
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib_compat.py", line 55, in 
>           Command = do_import("basecommand", "Command")
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib_compat.py", line 35, in do_import
>           _tmp = importlib.import_module(pip9)
>         File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.basecommand'

Anybody has any idea how I can correct this error?

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into a similar error during `pipenv lock`.

After updating pipenv via `pip install --user --upgrade pipenv` and pip via `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` the lock command resulted in an error message rather than the traceback.
This error message stated:

> There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to upgrade pipenv to the latest version. I had the same issue, now I installed version 2018.11.26, `pipenv lock` works flawlessly.

- Run `pip install pipenv --upgrade`, this will install the latest pipenv. If there's permission error use sudo as a prefix or add --user parameter.
- Once it's installed re-source the PATH by running source towards your shell config file, in my case `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue with pip 18.0 in Mac for virtual environment using pipenv (failing the pipfile.lock creation with this error message: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.basecommand'").
It was solved by `pip install --user --upgrade pipenv` to update pipenv (to pipenv-2018.11.14.).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Python 3.10 and Python 3.9 together. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. My packages only work in 3.9 and that's what the environment is set to. 3.10 is system Python.

The way I solved it was to use pipenv installed globally to shell into the 3.9 environment. Then when in there:

`pip3 install pipenv --upgrade`

If you run `which pipenv` outside of the virtual environment you'll get 3.10 and it will use /usr/bin/pipenv

If you run `which pipenv` inside of the virtual environment you'll get 3.9 and it will use the new virtual environment version which is 3.9 and should then `pipenv install` correctly.